# Pandas rounding doesn't work when specifying data types?

Tags: python, pandas, types, rounding

I have a problem where `pandas.round()` doesn't work as expected after defining my own datatypes. I am using v. 0.24.2.

Say that I have data as `float64` and I want to have my data as `float32` to save some memory, and I want to do some rounding:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dtypes = {'val': 'float32'}
my_decimals = {'val': 4}

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [0.14579999446868896]}) # <- this will be 'float64' 
df_mydtypes = df.astype(my_dtypes)

df_rounded = df.round(my_decimals)
df_mydtypes_rounded = df_mydtypes.round(my_decimals)
```

One might expect that the output is nevertheless `0.1458` after rounding to 4 decimals.

```
print(df_rounded['val'])
print(df_mydtypes_rounded['val'])

print(df_rounded['val'].item())
print(df_mydtypes_rounded['val'].item())
```

On the surface it looks good, but if we look closer (as my unittest did) the value is different:

```
0    0.1458
Name: val, dtype: float64
0    0.1458
Name: val, dtype: float32
0.1458
0.14579999446868896
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with a more general problem in computer science, and has to do with the way floats are stored. See ["Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in the Python docs for a detailed explanation.

Some ways to handle this:

- I noticed that `.values` or `.iloc` **do** produce the right number, but `to_list()` and `.item()` do not. I'm guessing this has to do with how `pandas` handles and produces the underlying `numpy` arrays.
- Python also has a [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module in case you need 'people' floats instead of computer ones...